# XPath query should return multiple results, but returns only one

Tags: xpath, vbscript

My XPath returns a list of values that I am assigning to a variable in VBScript, yet the result shows only one value.

How should I handle that?

```vb
Dim sXPath : sXPath = "/project//namespace/namespace/querySubject/queryItem[contains(., 'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/name"
Dim querySubject : Set querySubject = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
If querySubject Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo sXPath, "failed"
Else
    WScript.Echo "QuerySubjcet:", querySubject.text
```

Here the XPath returns a list:

```
Test
Database Layer
qsxyz
qixyz
```

but the output of the script is the first string only, i.e. `Test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you use `selectSingleNode` you get a single node, you rather want

```vb
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
  WScript.Echo node.text
Next
```